# What is the proper way to get constructive criticism about why my question is bad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes, feedback

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439564/how-to-keep-track-of-webpages-opened-in-web-browser-using-python) on stackoverflow. I was getting downvotes so I placed comments asking why the question is bad. Then there was a close vote as too broad. I countered that in a comment too and asked people to give counter-arguments to that before voting to close.

The odd thing that is happening is that at any time this question is having nearly the same number of upvotes and downvotes. It was -1 then -1/+1 then -2 then -2/+2 and at the time of asking of this question it is -3/+3. So I am not even sure what the downvoters are downvoting the question for. For starters, noone has replied to my comments.

So my question is how to get those downvoters to tell me why they are downvoting the question? At least I won't repeat the same mistake again.

On a side note, is the question really off-topic against the SO rules? Please read my comments before answering this question.

Comment: Posting here as you have done is also an option, and is more likely to get you answers than in the comments under your own question, where people are just going to tell you nobody's obligated to comment on their downvotes in order to excuse the silence.

Comment: Posting here is the right way to get feedback.  The question is simply too broad.  You need to do some work, write some code, then ask a more specific question that people can answer.  Right now you're just sorta asking for advice, which isn't really what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: You can use that [tag:specific-question] tag when requesting feedback about a particular question on Meta.

Comment: @AdamRackis About my question being too broad, I specifically said that I wanted to do that using standard Python libraries and specified my web-browser. Python has, generally, one way of doing things. So how then my question is too broad? Saying that it is too broad isn't meaningful at all when there hasn't been anyone telling 2 ways to do that using pure Python, so far.

Comment: It's too broad for Stack Overflow, simple as that.  You need to get some specific code written, and come ask when you get stuck with a specific part of it.  Saying "here's what I want to do, how should I do it" is too broad.

Comment: @AdamRackis There are a huge majority of questions here asking exactly in the same manner that I asked the questions. I searched "How can I" and one of the top results is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values). How is that not off-topic if mine is?

Comment: @AseemBansal I haven't even looked at that question, but your argument is flawed.  That some other question is open doesn't mean your question should also be open for being similar.  It means that either the questions are different enough, or that the other question should have been closed.  Regardless, your question will be evaluated on it's own based on the site's guidelines, not based on whether other similar questions are open or closed.

Comment: Others can post and disagree, but to me, asking how I "keep track of which webpages have been opened in my webbrowser" is a business requirement that can likely be solved in any number of ways.  Asking how to retrieve querystring values is a **programming question**.  It's like asking "how can I get the html from a div using jQuery"

Comment: @AdamRackis My question can very easily be rephrased as "How can I get current webpages open in firefox using Python?" without changing the gist which is essentially the same question with the programming language and what needs to be fetched changed. Also don't the question details matter in these cases?

Comment: @Servy So other similar highly upvoted questions don't mean community consensus on something? I was told in the meta on a previous occasion that the rules are not set in stone and community decision's matter.

Comment: You just need to start listening to what members of the community are telling you.  This question is too broad for SO.  We are not a forum that accepts any and all questions.  Learn what we are telling you.

Comment: @AseemBansal -- the question in your example is over 4 years old, back when question-appropriateness was a lot less clearly defined.  If that question were asked today, it would most likely get downvoted to oblivion and closed, but as it has over half a million views and over a thousand votes, I'm guessing it will stick around.

Comment: @AdamRackis Ok my question in the current form is too broad for SO then does rephrasing it as "How can I get current webpages open in firefox using Python?" make it any better or is it still too broad?

Comment: @AdamRackis Or should I take a particular approach and then ask question about that?

Comment: @AseemBansal in my opinion it is still the same question except you are explicitly stating the browser in the title (which you do state in the body, so it really isn't changing anything).  "How can I" question are very tough to do correctly in the current guidelines of SO.  They often work better as "How can I do Foo?  I found x and y, but they don't quite work because of z".

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ok. Thanks. I'll try to do that in the future.

Comment: @AseemBansal also questions that include "I don't know where to start" rarely do well without evidence of significant research.  The reasoning is the current guidelines expect that you use SO as a last resort and not a first stop, so when you are stating you don't know where to start and don't show what you have tried to do in order to figure it out, people assume you didn't do your research.

Comment: `"How can I do Foo? I found x and y, but they don't quite work because of z"`  Yeah - that.  That's what I was trying to find the words to describe.

Comment: @Aseem: You're asking for people to provide you with feedback regarding why it was closed, and then arguing with them when they answer you. Seems a little bit strange to me - if you don't want the feedback, why did you ask for it? I would have thought you would ask to *learn*, not to fight about it. (I didn't do so, but I would have voted to close your question as too broad - it's not nearly specific enough to be answered here.)

Comment: @KenWhite I was told on the question already that it was too broad. If the only feedback that I get here would be the same here then that wouldn't be helpful at all, would it? Giving the arguments due to which I thought it was on-topic and getting counter-arguments helped me understand. That's why I argued so that if my arguments are incorrect then let other people break them with counter-arguments.

Comment: Reading some of the resources on how to write a good question ([1](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), [2](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)) may help shed some light on the issue as well @Aseem

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to get feedback on a question is to ask for it on meta through a question.

My question was too broad because there was no research in it.